# What is this component with metal tabs?

Tags: identification

I am working with a [Firgelli Linear Actuator Control](http://www.firgelli.com/Uploads/LAC_Datasheet.pdf) board and came across an unusual component. At first I thought it was a heatsink, but there does not appear to be any component under the metal. It's very difficult to get a good image of it, but here are side and top views:

[image: Side]

[image: Top]

The inscribed label is:

```
X185F
UCK
```

Where the "X" could be some sort of logo (two intersecting V's, one inverted).

The three pins over it are for connecting RC servo input, and are not connected.

The lower metal tab is connected to Vcc as far as I can tell.

**Edit:**

The original link has broken. It appears the controller is also [an Actuonix Linear Actuator Control (LAC) board](https://www.actuonix.com/LAC-Board-p/lac.htm).

Comment: My thought was a fuse as well. The board isn't functioning and I'm trying to troubleshoot it. Both tabs measure 12V with respect to ground; only about 3mV difference between them.

Comment: Those two intersecting V's are found on many poly-fuses, so I suspect it's a kind of "fuse identification mark" as opposed to a manufacturers mark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [TE Connectivity SMD185F-2 PolySwitch](http://www.te.com/catalog/pn/en/RF1238-000?RQPN=SMD185F-2).

Comment: That's it exactly. Thank you, I wasn't having luck as I kept trying to include the second line or the manufacturer mark/logo.

Comment: Link-rot, but here it is:  http://www.newark.com/raychem-te-connectivity/smd185f-2/polyswitch-smd-1-85a/dp/42M2567